# How to change Symfony2 FOSUser register form error message?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have customized my register_content.html.twig like that

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST">
                <div id="fos_user_registration_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Pick a username' } }) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
                    </div>
                </div> ...
```

And now, when I'm getting an errors, those errors looks like that

```
fos_user.username.already_used
fos_user.email.already_used
fos_user.password.mismatch
```

I just want to change those messages, could anyone help me?

Comment: Did you enable the translator service in your application config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you enable the translator service, e.g.,

app\config\config.yml:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

copy the appropriate FOSUserBundle.{locale}.yml from `...vendor/friendsofsymfony/userbundle/Resources/translations` to `...app/Resources/translations`.  In the copied file, change the messages for

```
fos_user.username.already_used
fos_user.email.already_used
fos_user.password.mismatch
```